# Can't create runnable LWJGL jar with JarSplice

Tags: java, jar, lwjgl, slick2d

I created a runnable JAR with Eclipse for a small SLick2D game. No matter what settings I tried, I always received some sort of error, whether it be UnsatisfiedLinkError, or some class not being found.

I tried JARSplice, but that didn't work either.

Can anyone give me the steps to creating a runnable jar out of an Eclipse project?

Comment: You nees native libraries for LWJGL to work.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need is to somehow include the native libraries. You'll find them in the .zip you download from the lwjgl site.

I can recommend using JarSplice to package them. Make sure that when you specify what class it is supposed to run you do *not* use the default package (This is bad practice anyway). Specify the *whole* package path (e.g. package1.package2.Main), and it should run.

Use the packaged JAR generated by eclipse as your "input" jar of jarSplice.

Comment: One thing I never get is does the full path start at src, or what? You have basically quoted the text on jarsplice.

Answer (score 1):

If you use your command prompt to try and run your .jar after jarsplicing it, or using the manifest method, or whatever, you would go to the directory your .jar is in and type

java -jar YourGameNameHere.jar

This will give you the errors on why it will not run.